# What happens if inputStream is null for a AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, aws-lambda, try-catch, inputstream

So, I have to investigate if null InputStream goes to catch block of the code

Example code snippet::

```
public class TestLambda implements RequestStreamHandler {

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null && inputStream.available() != 0) {
                System.out.println("do something...");
      }
}      catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("in catch block");
}
```

My question is, if I do not put an else condition to the if block above and there is null inputStream, should the control go into catch block?

Answer (score 0):

No, control won't enter the exception block unless an `Exception` is thrown.  Just having a null inputStream alone will not cause an exception to be thrown because the `if` condition is checking if it is null.

Comment: I agree, also in the if block it is ANDed with inputStream.available() method so if inputstream is null then what are the chances that this available method might be throwing an exception?

Comment: Another line of thought is that since handleRequest() method itself shows IOException, it is also quite likely that this method is throwing an exception.

Comment: Java will short circuit, so if the first condition evaluates to false, it won't even evaluate the condition that comes after the "and" because it doesn't need to--knowing the first condition is false is sufficient.  That is why the null check exists first.  By checking null first, you can safely call the available method.  I don't understand your comment about IOException and don't see that anywhere in your code.